# demean and intercept in ar.ols()

Tags: r

The prototype of ar.ols() is

```
ar.ols(x, aic = TRUE, order.max = NULL, na.action = na.fail,
            demean = TRUE, intercept = demean, series, ...)

demean: should the AR model be for ‘x’ minus its mean?

intercept: should a separate intercept term be fitted?
```

I wonder what differences are between demean and intercept? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`demean` controls whether the data are demeaned before fitting the autoregressive model. If `demean=TRUE`, then you know in advance that the intercept will be 0 (up to rounding, machine, and other fitting error); as a result, `intercept` is by default quite sensibly set to `intercept=demean`.

In case you do still want the intercept term from a model fitted to the demeaned data, **or** in case you want to fit a model with no intercept to the un-demeaned data, `ar.ols()` gives you two arguments that support all possible permutations of data demeaning and intercept fitting:

```
x <- diff(log(EuStockMarkets))

## Equivalent to ar.ols( ... , demean = TRUE)$x.intercept
ar.ols(x, order.max = 6, demean = TRUE, intercept = TRUE)$x.intercept
#           DAX           SMI           CAC          FTSE 
#  5.108542e-06 -2.477317e-06  6.641355e-06 -3.423321e-06 

ar.ols(x, order.max = 6, demean = TRUE, intercept = FALSE)$x.intercept
# NULL

ar.ols(x, order.max = 6, demean = FALSE, intercept = TRUE)$x.intercept
#          DAX          SMI          CAC         FTSE 
# 0.0006940672 0.0007812742 0.0004866072 0.0004387839 

## Equivalent to ar.ols( ..., demean = FALSE)$x.intercept
ar.ols(x, order.max = 6, demean = FALSE, intercept = FALSE)$x.intercept
# NULL
```

Comment: thanks, Josh. I wonder if `intercept` means something to be subtracted from the time series, or a single constant term added to the model? See the first part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271445/interpret-the-output-of-ar-ols-for-a-bivariate-time-series.

Comment: another question: why the help page says "Some care is needed if ‘intercept’ is true and ‘demean’ is false.
     Only use this is the series are roughly centred on zero. Otherwise
     the computations may be inaccurate or fail entirely."

Comment: @Tim -- Sorry, I haven't ever analyzed time series data myself, so can't speak to these follow-up questions with any authority. I would have strongly assumed, though, that including an intercept term does mean adding a column of 1's to the model matrix, as it does in other model fitting functions. And a quick look at the body of `ar.ols` (see the call to `cbind(rep.int(1, nrow(y)), ...)` in the code block immediately following the first `if (intercept) {`) confirms this suspicion.